# Using FtpWebRequest on Amazon ec2 win2008R2 failing with Operation Timed Out

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp

We're using a simple FtpWebRequest in order to connect to an external FTP server using PASV mode. The issue is that the operation keeps timing out.

We've tried using ftp.exe (which does not support PASV), ncftp (which does) and WinSCP - and face the same issues - connections keep timing out.

Has anyone else faced the same problems? How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, best I can say is make sure that your security policies are set in both the Amazon EC2 console, and the server itself.

I had trouble at first connecting to FTP server because I forgot I also had to set the correct settings in the EC2 console.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Have confirmed that the security policies are set correctly on both the server and ec2 console. We are trying to connect to an FTP only - not serve via FTP. It appears that there is some severe packet loss occurring, which is why the connections time out.